# Insert null into double field in MS Access Database(not with parameters)

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, sql-insert, bulkinsert

I am trying to insert null value into Double field in MS Access Database but I can't. I am sharing my code below , can anyone help me?

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= RemovedDuplicateDt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {


                    checkBool = Convert.ToBoolean(RemovedDuplicateDt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString());

                    if (checkBool)
                    {
                        k = -1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        k = 0;
                    }

                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(RemovedDuplicateDt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString()))
                    {
                        scaling = DBNull.Value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        scaling = Convert.ToDouble(RemovedDuplicateDt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString());
                    }

                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " + "Data VALUES ('" + RemovedDuplicateDt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString() + "' ,"
                        + "'" + RemovedDuplicateDt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString() + "' ,"
                        + "'" + k + "' ,"
                        + "'" + Convert.ToDouble(string.IsNullOrEmpty(RemovedDuplicateDt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString()) ? "0" : RemovedDuplicateDt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(3)) + "' ,"
                        + "'" + Convert.ToDouble(string.IsNullOrEmpty(RemovedDuplicateDt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(4).ToString()) ? "0" : RemovedDuplicateDt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(4)) + "' ,"
                        + "'" + Convert.ToDouble(string.IsNullOrEmpty(RemovedDuplicateDt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(5).ToString()) ? "0" : RemovedDuplicateDt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(5)) + "' ,"
                        + "'" + RemovedDuplicateDt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(6).ToString() + "' ,"
                        + "'" + RemovedDuplicateDt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(7).ToString() + "' ,"
                        + "'" + Convert.ToInt16(string.IsNullOrEmpty(RemovedDuplicateDt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(8).ToString()) ? "0" : RemovedDuplicateDt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(8)) + "' ,"
                        + "'" + RemovedDuplicateDt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(9).ToString() + "' ,"
                        + "'" + RemovedDuplicateDt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(10).ToString() + "' ,"
                        + "'" + RemovedDuplicateDt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(11).ToString() + "' ,"
                        + "'" + Convert.ToInt32(string.IsNullOrEmpty(RemovedDuplicateDt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(12).ToString()) ? "0" : RemovedDuplicateDt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(12)) + "' ,"
                        + "'" + Convert.ToInt32(string.IsNullOrEmpty(RemovedDuplicateDt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(13).ToString()) ? "0" : RemovedDuplicateDt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(13)) + "' ,"
                        + "'" + RemovedDuplicateDt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(14).ToString() + "' ,"
                        + "'" + RemovedDuplicateDt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(15).ToString() + "' ,"
                        + "'" + RemovedDuplicateDt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(16).ToString() + "' ,"
                        + "'" + RemovedDuplicateDt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(17).ToString() + "' ,"
                        + "'" + Convert.ToInt32(string.IsNullOrEmpty(RemovedDuplicateDt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(18).ToString()) ? "0" : RemovedDuplicateDt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(18)) + "' )";

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
```

This code works but I dont want to see "0" in database, I want to see null(blank).

When I am trying to Convert.ToDouble(null) it throws an error, When I am trying to give DBNull.Value it throws an "DB missmatch criteria" error.

All I need is how to insert null into database with this code.

Dont want to use ;

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Scaling", Double.TryParse(RemovedDuplicateDt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString(), out result) ? (object)result : DBNull.Value);,
```

Because that usage is so slow,

And my Database design is like that ;

[image]

I am waiting for your response, thx!

Comment: In `RemovedDuplicateDt` that `double cell` contains `0` or` null`?

Comment: In RemovedDuplicateDt all cells in a String format & this cell is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use like this by changing this line

```
+ "'" + Convert.ToDouble(string.IsNullOrEmpty(RemovedDuplicateDt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString()) ? "0" : RemovedDuplicateDt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(3)) + "' ,"
```

to this

```
+ (string.IsNullOrEmpty(RemovedDuplicateDt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString()) ? "null" : RemovedDuplicateDt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(3)) + " ,"
```

**NOTE:**
But it will be better if you use **command parameters**, **concatenating SQL query** may cause [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), and this is big problem. Think that in your datatable cell value `'"); DROP TABLE Data ; -- "'`

Comment: Can you share that error line code? Couldn't see rihgt part of code

Comment: I edtied my answer, Use `paranthesis` to work `isnullorEmpty` correctly. And change line how I show, do not use `"'"` at the start

Comment: But dont understand why is your code not throws "data type missmatch error" ? Because db column type is double but you send "null" as an argument

Comment: this is literal null, sql accepts it as NULL value for any type